# Filebeat thows error "No outputs are defined. Please define one under the output section'

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I'm configuring Elasticsearch Kibana and Fileabeat to collect netflow. Everything seems fine. But filebate throw error
No outputs are defined. Please define one under the output section'

Comment: my Configuration

Comment: We need configuration file to tell you anything, please update your question.